# Updating Centos 8.0 to Centos 8.3

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel

I need your expert help on how can I update Centos 8.0 to Centos 8.3. I have installed Centos 8.0 using the standard option without GUI. It's a requirement at work. Please help

Thanks & regards,

Answer (score 0):

Really? The simplest of google searches will tell you how;

```
dnf check-update
```

then;

```
dnf update
```

Bear in mind that 8.5 is the last version, Centos was discontinued 1.5 years ago.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply just have one query tho, I had run DNF/yum, update so Cent-OS 8.0 will update to Cent-OS 8.5 is that it? but what if I need the 8.3 version specifically. I had some work specific requirement hence this update/upgrade

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to go to 8.5???

Comment: No specific reason there was a requirement hence asking. Also, are repositories available in centos 8.5?

Comment: It's best to start planning to move to another distro after what happened with Centos.